# Java Error while opening a large file of 2.2GB in appending mode which is inside a zipfile using java7 NIO

Tags: java, file-io, zip

While I'm trying to open a csv file of 2.2GB in append mode which is in a zip file whose size is 144MB, I get the following exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Negative initial size: -2030790440
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.<init>(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:74)
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.getOutputStream(ZipFileSystem.java:1371)
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.newOutputStream(ZipFileSystem.java:516)
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipPath.newOutputStream(ZipPath.java:792)
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:285)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:170)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedWriter(Files.java:2705)
    at
```

Here is the code snippet I'm using. 
code line :

```
filePath = "/tmp/tmp.zip";
Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
URI uri = URI.create("jar:" + path.toUri());
fs =  FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env);
Path nf = fs.getPath("detailedreport.csv");
Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(nf, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

**note** :
file already exists 
It seems like BufferWriter's int max limit is reached while reading the size of the file hence the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Sure seems like it. Maybe they'll increase the max array length to 64 bits some time in the future (probably not).

So are you stuck now? Why not unzip the file, append data and rezip it?

Answer (score 0):

Java can't handle more than Integer.MAX_VALUE that way as the underlying ByteArrayOutputStream is created with an int as parameter. See [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.java#ByteArrayOutputStream.%3Cinit%3E%28int%29)